# Temperature influence in Optical Quantum Computing

Tags: optics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I've recently been looking into the (perhaps a bit outdated but still very interesting) field of linear optical quantum computing. Using photons as information carriers, and using objects like mirrors, phase shifters and beam splitters to process information. Now, one thing seems to be very different from, for example, superconducting circuits. In superconducting circuits typical energies for the qubits are on the order of 8 GHz, or around 0.4K. So it has to be very cold in your experimental setup.

For photons on the other hand, we generally just use the (near)visible spectrum in the experiments, getting you on the order of 100 THz or several thousand K. This means (as you also see it done on your optics table) you don't need to perform the experiment in some type of fridge.

But how come this is relevant for photons? I don't completely understand the role of temperature here. In a superconducting circuits we have phonons and such, and we have energy levels that we want to be unoccupied, which becomes problematic at higher temperatures. But for photons, we don't work with different energy levels. So say we'd do our linear optics experiment in a room with temperature 10000K, what would change in the behaviour of the photon? (I understand that this temperature range won't be kind to your mirrors and such, but they don't set the energy scale in this example, so lets leave that out for a moment)

Comment: At the very least there will be a thermal background of photons that are indistinguishable from the ones that are used to do the computation. Having said that, unless optically active materials are being used, it seems unlikely that photons, all by themselves, can do much more than process a linear map. Am I missing something?

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, and is probably already the answer. But yes, photons by themselves are a bit lacking in the toolbox department, especially because it is hard to make photons interact. Doing a CNOT, for example, is quite a challenge, but you can do it with the Kerr effect. They still have applications in the communication department however, serving as 'flying qubits' that can transfer quantum information from one physical location to the other.

Comment: Well, as soon as you do it with the Kerr effect, it's not just photons but matter at a certain temperature and then you will get the usual thermodynamic interactions that will mix noise into the system. I don't think there is much of an advantage here, except for the scaling with $kT$.

Comment: I suppose you are correct, although the Kerr effect also works at room temperature of course. So if your biggest hurdle is having to cool down, then photons offer a nice solution. This isn't the case however.
Also, doing a little more searching, I found that there is actually a proposed scheme that lets you do universal quantum computing with only linear optics: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v409/n6816/full/409046a0.html 
That changes the story a little bit, but not too much I suppose. I think your initial comment solves my question though, background radiation should be distinguishable

Comment: I know about that article, but it's about as theoretical as a Turing machine. You can't buy one of those, either, because they are simply not sufficient as an engineering solution to information processing. In addition, the article performs a sleight of hand because it still needs a downconverter at the beginning and solves a lot of those pesky detail problems with handwaving.

Comment: This is very true. I've been studying the material as part of a course that introduces the systems that are being studied for quantum information processing nowadays (think about ion traps, NV centers, superconducting circuits) and the linear optics is included more as a historical part, as a lot of early work and first implementations were done with them. But I agree with you, I personally do not see them as a viable system to perform operations on, more of a potential option to transfer information with from qubit to qubit.

Comment: I am not totally skeptical of photonic quantum computing. The experimental challenges are simply in finding materials which have sufficiently strong interactions (certainly much stronger than Kerr) in very small volumes, which probably calls for layered semiconductors or something similar. One also has to overcome the very short decoherence times with ultrafast optics, but that's less of a challenge today than it was a few decades ago.